# Question about the limit of a sequence

Tags: calculus

I know that
$$\sum\frac{1}{n}=\infty$$
then what's the limit of the following
$$\sum\frac{1}{a+bn}$$
where $a,b>0$

Comment: Do you know the limit comparison test?

Answer (score 5):

Note that
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{a+bn}\geq \frac1b\sum_{n=a+1}^\infty \frac1n=\infty$$

Answer (score 0):

Compare it ! Put $a_n = \frac{1}{n}$ and $b_n = \frac{1}{a + bn} $.

Then $$\lim \frac{a_n}{b_n} = \lim \frac{\frac{1}{n}}{\frac{1}{a + bn}} = \lim \frac{a + bn}{n} = b > 0  $$

$$ \therefore \sum b_n \; \; \; \text{ DIVERGES by limit comparison test}$$